# FileName -FilePath comparison

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to compare the 2 file names.

I build a file name and then compare it to the one in the directory. My code is not able to compare the strings. Please let me know, what am I doing wrong? There are no errors, but the the strings is never equal.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
Filename = "Account Daily " + dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " .xslx";

FileInfo[] folderFiles = null;
folderFiles = dir1.GetFiles();
foreach (FileInfo aFile in folderFiles)
{
    if (String.Compare(aFile.ToString(),Filename) == 1)
    {
        // Send email with this attachment
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a debugger and step through your code to see by yourself, what's going on.

Comment: if you're only checking if the strings are equal, you could use `string1==string2`

Comment: When testing, I found It is true for one file name, which is in the same foler, that does not match the name at all. It is true for the "Batch_job_SP" file. Wonder why?.1) Account Daily 2017-11-08 2_ Account Daily  2017-11-13  3)Batch_Job_SP_DB.xslx.

Comment: @SaraDob, check Szeki answer and his link.

Comment: I tried  string.compare as per @Szeki. The results still dont match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String.Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare(v=vs.110).aspx) returns 0 if the two arguments match. So if you want to enter the `if`, the comparison should check against that value.

Here's a reference:

```
|           Value           | Condition                                                                       
|-------------------------- |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Less than zero            | The first substring precedes the second substring in the sort order.            
| Zero                      | The substrings occur in the same position in the sort order, or length is zero. 
| GreaterGreater than zero  | The first substring follows the second substring in the sort order.
```

Comment: You could add to your answer that `String.Compare` returns Less than zero if The first substring precedes the second substring in the sort order and Greater than zero if The first substring follows the second substring in the sort order.

Comment: @Magnetron Indeed, I copied the reference table

Answer (score 2):

FileInfo.ToString() returns the whole access path (e.g. **c:/temp/** file.xml)

Source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.fileinfo.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx

Unfortunately, the value you assigned to the Filename variable is a plain file name without the access path. Therefore it cannot be equal to anything FileInfo.ToString() gives you.

Suggestion : You could use **aFile.Name** instead of **aFile.ToString()**

Comment: small remark : `FileInfo.ToString()` return an **absolute path**

Comment: Not always, from your link "The string returned by the ToString method represents path that was passed to the constructor...  For example, when you create a FileInfo object using the GetFiles method, the ToString method does not represent the fully qualified path." He used the GetFiles so it will not return the full path.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're trying to do is check to see if there is a particular file in a particular folder, then you could use the `GetFiles()` overload that has a searchpattern argument to find files that appear to have today's date:

```
Directory.GetFiles("c:\\my\\path", $"*{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}.xlsx");
```